# Could New Orleans have been saved without Cloak & Dagger's solution?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, cloak-and-dagger

In the season 1 finale of *[Marvel's Cloak & Dagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak_&_Dagger_(TV_series))*, Tandy and Tyrone are revealed to be a "divine pairing" and that in order to save New Orleans, one of them must die due to destiny. Tyrone decides that he's going to sacrifice himself. He teleports in and then pokes at the computers, not sure what to do.

But then Tandy comes in and tells him that they're going to defy fate. They come to the solution to use their powers together to destroy the machinery and then teleport away, thus saving the city without either of them dying.

The episode definitely presents this as the two having defied their fate where one must die to save the city. But I'm wondering: how could the city have possibly have been saved with just Tyrone or just Tandy? Tyrone didn't seem to know what he was doing with the computers before Tandy arrived, and Tandy didn't seem to have any ideas.

Is there any way that New Orleans could have been saved in such a way that one of them would have been able to work alone, but at the cost of their life? I ask because it's not so much defying destiny if the destiny they build up with the previous stories of divine pairings didn't actually apply to them.

Comment: The final scene has me thinking it wasn't a solution or that or the crisis hasn't actually arrived yet.

Comment: @Izkata Do you want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Wasn't exactly sure it counts, but alright

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Very doubtful

As it was presented on the show, both Tandy and Tyrone needed to be present. Each of them only had one half of the power, shadow and light, and neither of them could have absorbed it alone, especially not without the apparent boost from touching.

Further, both Tyrone *and* Tandy had the scar by the end (notice that the camera lingers on Tandy's burn, which looks the same as Tyrone's injury). If Evita's aunt mostly knows what she's talking about, then this means that they are both marked by destiny. *Both* of them have to be the ones to save the city. Both are destined to do so.

Although it wasn't laid out explicitly, it seems clear to me that the essential misunderstanding (if that's what it was... could be Auntie was being clever) was that it wasn't about death. It was about *sacrifice.* Like the story of Abraham and Isaac, it was about the *willingness* to give up one's life or one's most important person.

> TANDY: I'm not gonna let you die in here.
>
> TYRONE: One of us has to.
>
> TANDY:  Then we both have to. For some reason, life tossed us together and mixed up our mojo, so if it's on you, it's on me, too, I know that.

We can't necessarily take the images that accompanied Auntie's stories as definitive, but it seems that all the other pairings achieved their sacrifice at the moment they decided they were willing to give their life.

After all, did the fighting in the war of 1812 miraculously end when the soldier died? Of course not. It ended when the refugee passed on his information...but because of his sacrifice.

> As legend has it, he died in the arms of a young refugee, and with but a look, he passed his urgency on to her.
> **His mission was executed.**

Because Tandy and Tyrone were both willing to die, because they both put thenselves in that situation of near certain death not expecting to come out of it, they fulfilled their divine pairing.

Answer (score 1):

In the final scene of the season,

> The copy who was gassed and shot mid/late in the final episode, Brigid O'Reilly, is seen crawling up out of the swap.  When she turns to look back, her eyes have been altered, and as she walks away she flickers several feet in a second.

This has me believing one of two things:

- This signals that the catastrophe they're supposed to stop is coming in Season 2.
- They did stop the foretold catastrophe, but having done so incorrectly they now face an extension of it that never occurred in the past, and so never made it into the "divine pairing" stories.